# Never ending PID processes when trying to launch Postgres

Tags: postgresql, macos

I've installed Postgres via Homebrew, and when I run in my terminal:

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

I receive the following error, I've now killed atleast 50 processes, and it feels like an infinite loop, which can't be right. How do I move past this?

```
    2021-11-10 11:24:38.646 CET [36599] FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
2021-11-10 11:24:38.646 CET [36599] HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 36583) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?
```

I've also ran the following, still another one just replaces it.

```
     sudo lsof -i :5432
COMMAND    PID        USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
postgres 36689 cory    7u  IPv6 0x2051737000915f5f      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)
postgres 36689 cory    8u  IPv4 0x2051736ffd964a9f      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

The server is already running, so if you want to start it, you have to stop it first.

PostgreSQL has a lot of safeties build in that make it hard for you to start two servers on the same data directory, as that would cause data corruption. Seems like these safeties were good enough to keep you from damage.

To stop the PostgreSQL server, you can either run the following as operating system user `postgres`:

```sh
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop
```

or you can read the PID file `/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` and `kill` the process number you find in there. **Always use `kill`, never use `kill -9`.**